# Where can I post a test question to gain a hat or check the criteria for awarding a secret hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats

I want to post a test question to either:

- Gain a Winter Bash hat, or
- Test a theory about the criteria for awarding a secret hat.

Where can I post such a test question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers in the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), and as a moderator questions can be posted on [your own site](https://superuser.com/) where you can permanently delete the question afterwards.

In the Sandbox similar rules to posting elsewhere apply, as a moderator we're sure you'll be reasonable.